# Javascript fetch wait for page to load completely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, asynchronous, fetch

Currently when I am attempting to fetch an image from my URL I get the HTML with an embedded image string. This is because the image needs to go through some processing before being sent. The problem is, because of this delay, I never manage to fetch this image. It takes about a second for it to be processed. I am so confused what is the best practice to solve this problem?

```
var imageUrl = 'https://get_image.com/image_id';
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'text/html');
fetch(imageUrl,{
    headers: myHeaders
}).then(function(response) {
    response.text().then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
    })
});
```